# How do I know which application is selected by user in Sharing Intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have used Sharing Intent in my application so that user can share some content from my app using Facebook, Twitter, Gmail etc. I have successfully done this but my problem is that I just want to know that which application is get selected by user from Intent Chooser.

I have gone through some examples and questions but not able to find any helpful answer so if anyone can help me to sort out this it would be very helpful for me.

Any help would be appreciable, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[clickclickclack](http://clickclickclack.wordpress.com/2012/01/03/intercepting-androids-action_send-intents/) has an example implementation of how you can intercept the ACTION_SEND intent and choose what ends up happening. You can modify this sample for your situation.

Comment: but in this example he is using a custom list view to select an intent  and I am using the default intent chooser list.

Comment: @SalmanKhan Yea you will have to use a custom intent chooser for this solution. Just a suggestion, there might be an easier way.

Comment: one more question friend, in that custom list I need to give the app package names on my own or something else should be done for this?